# Verifying public key visually

Tags: certificates, random

Verifying a string of long numbers is hard (think of cert public key). I remember there is a tool to visualize this randomness into a "randomness graph" but I cannot recall what is the graph called and how to generate it.

So, the question:

1. What is the name of the graph used to help visualize randomness?
2. How to generate such graph given a certificate?

Comment: Are you thinking of the VisualHostKey used in OpenSSH? https://tylercipriani.com/blog/2017/09/26/ssh-key-fingerprints-identicons-and-ascii-art/

Comment: I realize it doesn’t answer your question, but you’re a lot better off using “grep” or “diff” to verify the strings are the same; or checking the signatures are valid.  Eyeballs can do only so much, but the computer can ensure a match every time.

Comment: @JohnDeters: agreed, I use those when I must verify it exactly. But in some use cases, randomart is sufficient, e.g. displaying the fingerprint on ssh login or when I cannot get both cert in the same "session" and I don't need to compare them exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about randomarts, you can use the following web app to generate them in an easy way:

https://sshvis.appspot.com/

In order to try it you only need the Fingerprint, for this example I use the following:

```
‎04:aa:3a:d8:25:83:95:72:ad:c7:8e:16:ce:25:26:33
```

The output will be:

```
+-----------------+
|      .          |
|   o . .         |
|. + o   .        |
| = +   .         |
|E O =   S        |
|.X @             |
|+ * .            |
| o               |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

I also attach a screenshot as a reference:

[image: SSH Fingerprint Visualization]

Comment: Yes, it is "randomart"! Once the keyword is known, the internet is open :)

Thanks @galoget.

Comment: Perfect, Glad to hear that, you're welcome @tkokasih ! =)